# C# NPOI rowStyle

Tags: c#, npoi

Ii have applied `NPOI` to generate the excel. So far so good except that I want to bold a row.

I have tried:

```
tmpRow.RowStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
tmpRow.RowStyle.SetFont(boldFont);
```

However, nothing has changed.

While I can do it by setting it one by one:

```
ICellStyle boldFontCellStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
IFont boldFont = workbook.CreateFont();
boldFont.IsBold = true;
boldFontCellStyle.SetFont(boldFont);
for (int p= 0; p <= 12; p++)
{
    tmpRow.GetCell(p).CellStyle = boldFontCellStyle;
}
//tmpRow.RowStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
//tmpRow.RowStyle.SetFont(boldFont);
```

I would like to know if there is any way to set an entire row style in `NPOI`?

Thanks.

Comment: It should be possible using the properties you used, as shown [here](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi/blob/02f080d3ee37e4f04a999be32604b1cb6bf3e649/examples/xssf/SetRowStyle/Program.cs).
I had the same problem when updating an existing workbook, which was fixed by calling sheet.CreateRow(n), instead of GetRow(n), which seemed to have individual cell styles that were overriding the row style.

Answer (score 3):

Try this for Row styling

```
XSSFFont defaultFont = (XSSFFont)workbook.CreateFont();
defaultFont.FontHeightInPoints = (short)10;
defaultFont.FontName = "Arial";
defaultFont.Color = IndexedColors.Black.Index;
defaultFont.IsBold = true;

XSSFCellStyle yourCellStyle = (XSSFCellStyle)workbook.CreateCellStyle();
yourCellStyle.SetFont(defaultFont);

var row = sheet.CreateRow(0);
row.RowStyle = yourCellStyle;
```

Below one was for cell style

```
 XSSFFont yourFont = (XSSFFont)workbook.CreateFont();
    yourFont.FontHeightInPoints = (short)12;
    yourFont.FontName = "Arial";               
    yourFont.IsBold = true;
    yourFont.IsItalic = false;
    yourFont.Boldweight = 700;
    XSSFCellStyle yourStyle = (XSSFCellStyle)workbook.CreateCellStyle();
    yourStyle.SetFont(yourFont);
    for (int p= 0; p <= 12; p++)
      { 
        row.Cells[p].CellStyle = yourStyle;
      }
```

Comment: I only copied the " for" loop part intentionally for your convenience. Above that I have provided you my workable code. you may try it  if you like.

Comment: the point is, if i don't mind to add the cellstyle one by one, my code could work too, i am looking for something like row style, instead of cellStyle :)

Comment: Try the approach I suggested to you now.

Answer (score 1):

Generate style, set it and then apply it to row. Something like this:

```
var rowStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
rowStyle.SetFont(boldFont);

tmpRow.RowStyle = rowstyle;
```